# Is there any scriptural basis for this astrologer's claims that the character of a woman depends on the timing of her first menstruation?

Tags: scripture, astrology, women, calendar

I was watching a YouTube video recently where the speaker said that one astrologer in his [pañcāṅga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchangam) (almanac) claimed that a woman's character and what the woman goes on to become in her later life depends on the time of the day she menstruates for the first time. I didn't believe him first but after a bit of googling I did find a couple of references. [Here's one](http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/Hyderabad/case-against-astrologer-for-comments-in-almanac/article3017568.ece) (The Hindu). And [this is the other](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/indiahome/indianews/article-2117770/Womens-groups-arms-almanac-predictions.html) from which I quote below.

> Gargeya's almanac (panchangam in Telugu) called 'Graha Bhoomi Panchangam' for the Telugu New Year 2012-13 (it begins on March 23) has some strange observations about the menstruation period of girls.
>
> The almanac predicts that if a girl gets her first menstruation after sunset, she will become a prostitute.
>
> And that's not all. 'If the menstrual cycle starts in the evening, the girl will turn into a thief and if she attains puberty at around midnight, she will become a widow at an early age and will have sagging breasts.
>
> 'And if it happens after midnight, she will become a destitute,' Gargeya's almanac claims.
>
> **. . .**
>
> Gargeya, though, defended his almanac. 'The observations had been there in the almanac for years and there is nothing offensive
>   about them,' he said.

Since the astrologer is defending his claims, I thought there must be a precedent for this. So do any jyotiṣa śāstras discuss this matter?

Comment: Its individual claim maybe. Or some spurious astro text

Comment: And what about after sunrise and noon?

Comment: All the Panjikas I have have this info in details.. Not sure where they quote from though..

Answer (score 2):

The fate/destiny of any person would be prerecorded in their horoscope at their birth date,time,place. Birth chart is a DVD-R cassette. The horoscope is used as a video casette and one can view it to know various life event timings and quality.

The event may be anything, it only happens according to their fate.

If it is already destined in a girl's horoscope that she would become as so, then, that girl would have her first menstruation only in such type of evil period. Timing of life events always follows the birth chart.

In case of absence of birth chart, an astrologer can also know their fate by the timing of first menstruation.

In fact, an astrologer can take any life event to determine one's future, like, at the time of purchasing a vehicle, or can take the time of beginning of education, etc.

All life events of a person show only one direction destination path.

Comment: "In case of absence of birth chart, an astrologer can also know their fate by the timing of first menstruation." - please add some references to support this statement. Also, take a look at [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126).

Comment: Everything can not be shown in scriputres verses books. it is an astrologers experience. I have not come here to copy paste answers from text books you tubes which is known as lack of knowledge and inexperience in my opinion. 
I don't insist people to believe my answers. An astrologer gains much capability by practicing hundreds of horoscopes and develops many techniques.

Comment: "it is an astrologers experience" - unfortunately, personal experience is of not much value on _this_ site (see site [FAQ](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/266/2995) ). Answers should be supported by scriptures or words of gurus/acharyas or other credible authority.

Comment: Yes, I know, value is not there in this site. If moderators or administrators tell me to stop, then I shall obey them and shall stop writing. Fortunately, I don't bother/cry for value, debates, reputation. Thanks

Comment: I don't have any proofs. Please delete the answer. I don't have any objections. Your site. Your wish.

Answer (score 2):

Surya Narayan Rao, the grandfather of BV Ramana, wrote Stri Jataka, and in chapter two he discusses "Arthava Lagna" the horoscope drawn for the time of the girl's first menses.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It may not be clear to a bot but to humans it is clear.